# How can I compare the artifacts that would be published with a specific version in my maven repository?

Tags: gradle, maven-publish

I'm using Gradle's `maven-publish` plugin to publish artifacts to a maven repository.

I'd like to have a programmatic way to tell to tell if the artifacts that my current build would publish are identical to those of a specified previously published version already in the maven repository.

For example, if my README is edited, I'd expect that to have no effect on the resulting artifacts to publish. I'd like to have a programmatic way of confirming this, so that I can avoid publishing new versions unnecessarily.

How can I check this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by comparing the md5 hash sum of the artifacts.
For example you can use the rest api on nexus to get the sum of what is in your repo.
Generate the hash for the one you build and publish/dont publish based on that.

Comment: This sounds like a promising approach. How do I ask gradle to generate the current md5?

Comment: I did some more poking around, and an additional complication with this approach is that the md5s for jars are not stable because they contain the build timestamp! [Apparently I'm not the only one to run into this issue](https://github.com/KittyHawkCorp/stripzip). Either the jars need to be stripped/normalized before publishing, or we need to compare the actual jar (not just md5) in a way that ignores meaningless differences.